# Autorelease NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, autorelease

Am I responsible for releasing this string, and is it autorelease by default?

```
// command is of type NSData*
char cAddress[12];
[command getBytes:cAddress range:NSMakeRange(5,12)];
NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar*)cAddress length:12];
```

Comment: Regarding the topic, read and memorize the [Object Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1).

Comment: If you don't use the autorelease when you declara the variable, you have to [release] the item in program.

Comment: @MarkSiu Unless the method returns an autoreleased object, which this method does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's autoreleased by default.
Retained objects are usually created with methods in the form of:

```
[[MyClass alloc] ...]
[MyClass new] 
[object copy]
```

Comment: Or any method that *contains* alloc/new/copy. Please, please read the Memory Management Programming Guide (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). It is the one true memory reference for Cocoa memory management.

Comment: I agree. Really important document.

Answer (score 4):

Autoreleased by default.